# Images uploaded using media uploader are appearing upside down

Tags: functions, images, uploads

A client of mine has come to me with an issue I've never seen before.

Some of the images he's uploaded via the media uploader are appearing upside down or sideways.

I'm assuming it's because they were taken on a phone and Wordpress is preserving the direction in which they were shot?

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: This sounds like solving your problem: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-the-automatically-image-rotation-fuction-in-wordpresswp-core

Comment: @rfrq please move that to an answer and elaborate a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either one of those plugins should fix the problem:

- http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-fixer/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-rotation-repair/